# How do I NOT display pair of duplicates in (zsh) history?

Tags: grep, zsh, command-history

My default shell is `zsh` and let's say my history looks like this:

```
command a
command b
command a
command b
command c
command b
command a
command b
command a
command b
```

Now what I would like to have is rather something like:

```
command a
command b
command c
command b
command a
command b
```

Optimally this would be achieved by not storing the duplicate pairs of command at all but if there is a way to display it like I wish to have it with a neat `grep`, I'm totally fine with that too.

Comment: why not remove all of the duplicate commands?

Comment: I wish to know the order of executed commands, if I need to retrace something. However whether I executed the said pair of commands once or 500x doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to train yourself to enter your commands a bit differently to be able to get what you want. This works:

```bsh
% setopt histignoredups 
% print a; print b 
a
b
% print a; print b
a
b
% print a; print c
a
c
% print a; print b
a
b
% print a; print b
a
b
% history
    1  setopt histignoredups
    2  print a; print b
    3  print a; print c
    4  print a; print b
%
```

Otherwise, Zsh doesn't have any way of knowing what you consider "pairs".